# Domain and range of $\sqrt {x^2-2x-8}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the domain and range of:
$$y=\sqrt {x^2-2x-8}$$

My Attempt:
For domain,
$y$ is defined iff
$$x^2-2x-8\geq 0$$
$$(x-4)(x+2)\geq 0$$
$$x\in (-\infty, -2]\cup [4, \infty)$$

For Range,
$$y=\sqrt {x^2-2x-8}$$
$$y=\sqrt {(x-1)^2 - 9}$$
$$y^2=(x-1)^2-9$$
$$y^2+9=(x-1)^2$$

Comment: Shouldn't the range be y =>0 as this is in the real plane?

Comment: Technically I am unsure what are we supposed to do. Anyway what you say is true enough.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @Dave, what's the range of the function?

Comment: You've found the domain. One way to find the range is to find the minimum of the function on its domain (call this point $a$). Then, since the function is clearly unbounded on this domain, the range will be $[f(a),\infty)$, since the range is certainly a subset of $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

When you squared $y$ you introduced spurious solutions.  Your work on the domain shows $y$ can go to $0$ and when $x$ gets large in either direction $y$ gets large and positive.  What does that tell you about the range?

Comment: @ Ross Millikan, No idea about that. Could you please explain?

Comment: Your final equation has a solution $(6,-4)$ which the original equation does not.  That might convince you that $-4$ is in the range, but the original requires $y \ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the term inside of the square root goes from $0$ to $+\infty$ in either direction. Therefore, $y$ would also go from $0$ to $\infty$